# Criar variaveis com um array de forma dinamica

Tags: php

Declarar variaveis de forma dinamica

```
for($i = 0; $i < 10 ; $i++)
{   
    $arry[$i]= "var" .$i;
    echo $arry[$i] . "<br>";
    $$arry[$i] = "ok";  //<-Aqui queria que a variavel $var'i' = "ok"
}

 echo $var0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para transforma elementos de um array em variáveis use a função `extract()`, se forem muitos elementos não faz muito sentido utilizar.

É recomendado passar como argumento a opção `EXTR_SKIP` isso evita que caso uma variável com esse nome já existe tenha seu valor sobrescrito.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $arr['var'.$i] = 'ok '. rand(1,99);
}

extract($arr, EXTR_SKIP);
```

Outra forma de definir um prefixo nas variáveis é usar a opção `EXTR_PREFIX_ALL` assim cada elemento terá o nome informado seguido de um underline. Nesse exemplos os nomes serão `$var_0`, `$var_1` etc

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    $arr[$i] = 'var'.$i;
}

extract($arr, EXTR_SKIP|EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'var');
```

Pode ver as variáveis criadas na execução do script dessa forma:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Manual - extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

[Manual - get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)